# copy and paste according to a order in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-office-2010

I want a macro that will fetch data from Series B and Automatically paste it according to the serial of Serial A. ASeries B and Series A data are same but Series B is not ordered. So i'm looking for something that will put Series B data in Series C column according to the order of Series A.

Is that possible?

Series B is in Column F on sheet 1. Numbers are 1-30 (F2:F31) and in ascending order

Series A is in Column A on sheet 1. The target cells to be filled up are (A2:A31)

Series C is in column A on sheet 2. Numbers are 1-30 but not in order (1,30,25,16,14,8 etc). (A2:A31)

P.S: I Cannot Post images. Not enough reputation

Comment: Can you explain more about the different orders? For instance, is one sheet ordered ascending and the other descending? A macro sounds unlikely but perhaps it will help if you have a header row at the top and hit the Filter button (on the Data tab of the ribbon). This would allow you to sort by any column on sheet 2 before the copy/paste. Also it will  help if you say what version of Excel you're using (add a tag for that version).

Comment: actually the orders are not ascending or descending. but I have to paste values from worksheet 2 (A1:A30) according to the order of worksheet 1 Column F (A1:A30)

Comment: Since sheet 2 contains the same numbers, how is this any different from copying sheet 1 column F to sheet 1 column A?

Comment: Is there any way that I can use tables to show the problem? I guess I cannot clarify the question

Comment: Yes, edit the question and you'll see a question-mark icon top right above the edit box. Click that for formatting info. I don't know if actual HTML tables are supported, but if nothing else you could type your tables as Code, which is monospaced.

Comment: Or you can do a screensshot and include the image in your question.

Comment: I saw your edit but I still can't make sense of your actual data! But anyway, it does make sense that you're trying to write a macro to populate a column according to the contents of another column. What have you tried? What problem have you encountered? The site is not about someone writing a macro for you, but folks are more than happy to try and help you overcome a specific technical issue writing a macro.